# Replace the value of an specific cell by using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mySQL db and I want to replace in the table **pageViews**, shown below, all the *page* values "secondPage" to "other":

| user | page | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | mainPage | 2021-01-10 04:37:14 |
| 1 | mainPage | 2021-01-10 10:37:24 |
| 2 | mainPage | 2021-01-10 20:37:44 |
| 3 | mainPage | 2021-01-10 20:10:14 |
| 4 | mainPage | 2021-01-11 00:02:04 |
| 2 | secondPage | 2021-01-12 00:03:04 |
| 4 | mainPage | 2021-01-13 00:31:04 |
| 5 | mainPage | 2021-01-14 20:23:04 |
| 2 | mainPage | 2021-01-15 10:37:04 |

So it would be:

| user | page | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | mainPage | 2021-01-10 04:37:14 |
| 1 | mainPage | 2021-01-10 10:37:24 |
| 2 | mainPage | 2021-01-10 20:37:44 |
| 3 | mainPage | 2021-01-10 20:10:14 |
| 4 | mainPage | 2021-01-11 00:02:04 |
| 2 | other | 2021-01-12 00:03:04 |
| 4 | mainPage | 2021-01-13 00:31:04 |
| 5 | mainPage | 2021-01-14 20:23:04 |
| 2 | mainPage | 2021-01-15 10:37:04 |

I think that using the REPLACE command I can do it, but I don´t know how to do it. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply update page column where value is **secondPage** with **other**. Replace is not necessary here.

```
update pageViews set page='other' where page='secondPage';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update pageviews set page = 'other' where page like 'secondPage'
```

Comment: Is there any good reason for using `like` without wildcards?